# bullets list element disappear in IE7

Tags: css, html-lists

I see this question has been asked in inertia, yet the suggestions I see in other posts Ive had no luck with at [this site](http://charmcitykids.missionmedia.net).  It's the top right menu, "join our email list," "contact us," "directions,"

I tried using background image but in doing so it kills the speaker icon background image next to the word music.

Each instance for each coder is different, thus maybe another coder here sees something I missed; suggest a tip?

Answer (score 0):

Do list-style-type:none; for the #nav

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help: http://haslayout.net/css/Image-Float-Bullet-Chaos-Bug